# How to add new entry into existing XML file (except DOM)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There is an existing `xml` file & `xsd`. as i want to write new data into the existing `xml` file without affecting any old data?

file.xml

```
<project>
    <session>
       <id>1234</id>
       <name>abcd</name>
    </session>
</project>
```

Now i want new entry `id= 5678 & name = wxyz` and my expected result should be,

```
<project>
    <session>
       <id>1234</id>
       <name>abcd</name>
    </session>
    <session>      // New Entry
       <id>5678</id>
       <name>wxyz</name>
    </session>
</project>
```

How am i trying to do :
1. unmarshal the xml file to java object and save into ArrayList
2. get the new value and add into ArrayList
3. Marshal the object to existing XML file.

using `DOM` it's very easy to do but i want to use `jaxb`, is there any simple tutorial or do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JAXB here is very simple. Take a look here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html

It is not very detailed tutorial but I believe it is a good start and enough to implement your task.

Then take this one: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks AlexR ! I am going through the first link.